# Parsing JSON data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yahoo-api

So I'm using Yahoo's API to translate coordinates to a zip code.  The JSON it returns is this:

```
{
"ResultSet": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "Error": 0,
    "ErrorMessage": "No error",
    "Locale": "us_US",
    "Quality": 99,
    "Found": 1,
    "Results": [{
         ....
     }]
```

What I am doing is:

```
$.getJSON("http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=" + lat + ",+" + lon + "&gflags=R&flags=J", function(data){
            console.log(data.ResultSet.Results.postal);
        });
```

What I listed above obviously doesn't work.  My question is: how do I access the data within the Results array?

Thanks

Comment: How to work with arrays is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as Results is an array does changing the console log line to the following work?

```
console.log(data.ResultSet.Results[0].postal)
```

In which case just loop through the array to get each each element. The code to get JSON looks fine to me, I assume you just missed the array element bit :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$.getJSON("http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=234532,234533&gflags=R&flags=J", function(data){
   $.each(data.ResultSet.Results,function(i,item){
      console.log(data.ResultSet.Results[i].postal);
   });     
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/ALsHH/11/

Answer (score 0):

The line `console.log(data.ResultSet.Results.postal);` is attempting to access a property called `portal` on an object called `data.ResultSet.Results` however the property doesn't exist as Results is an array of objects.

What you'll probably need to do is iterate of the array something like...

```
$.getJSON("http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=" + lat + ",+" + lon + "&gflags=R&flags=J", function(data){
    for (var i=0; i< data.ResultSet.Results.length; i++) {
        console.log("data.ResultSet.Results[i].postal = " + data.ResultSet.Results[i].postal);
});
```